# How to create a celestial sphere with Java

Tags: javafx-8

I have created a simple simulation of a satellite around a planet using JavaFX. It would be nice to have this simple universe surrounded by a celestial sphere with stars mapped on the sphere. Is there any way to do this using JavaFX (e.g., is it possible to apply a phongmaterial to the inside of a sphere)? If not, is there any free library/tool that I can use to create the celestial sphere for my JavaFX application?

Comment: May help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806286/create-photo-sphere-similar-to-google-map-photo-sphere-javafx-3d

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot.